# How to refresh aspx page from sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to refresh aspx page from sql server.I am using asp.net,C-Sharp with SQL Server 2008.What i mean is i have table, say **Table1**.If any DML operation is performed (Update,Insert etc) to **Table1**,then my page,say **Page1.aspx** should autmatically get refreshed.I can't use **timer** for refreshing the page.I need to trigger the refresh from database.

Comment: Should the page get refreshed even if the browser is closed?

Comment: @Oded:-I guess my purpose won't be solved by closing the browser

Comment: have a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437309/how-to-refresh-a-page-when-record-in-db-table-get-changed-in-asp-net-3-5

Comment: **http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/caching-data/using-sql-cache-dependencies-vb**

Comment: Are you trying to update the page in real-time or on the next postback?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though the server may be notified when data has changed, the real challenge is communicating those changes to the client in real-time without requiring a timer or user interaction.

You have a couple of options:

1. Your best bet is to use a [WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), which enables bidirectional communication between the client and server. This is the solution I would pick.

   Here are some examples using `WebSockets`:

   - [Building real-time web apps with WebSockets using IIS, ASP.NET and WCF](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/SAC-807T)
   - [HTML5 C# WebSockets Server and ASP.NET Client Implementation](http://www.undisciplinedbytes.com/2010/06/html-5-c-web-sockets-server-and-asp-net-client-implementation/)
   - [C# WebSocket Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211898/c-sharp-web-socket-server)
   - [WebSockets in ASP.NET 4.5](http://www.techbubbles.com/aspnet/websockets-in-asp-net-4-5/)
   - [WebHooks and WebSockets in ASP.NET](http://www.entechsolutions.com/hooks-and-sockets-for-web-apps)

   There are a few good libraries around too that will take care of most of the leg work. A couple to check out are [WebSync](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync/downloads#server) and [PokeIn](http://www.pokein.com/Products/Downloads.aspx). Both products offer decent documentation and community editions that you can download for free.

   Here are some tutorials to check out:

   - [WebSync Tutorials](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync/support/tutorials/v3)
   - [PokeIn Basic Tutorial](http://www.pokein.com/Help/BasicTutorial.aspx) / [PokeIn Advanced Tutorial](http://www.pokein.com/Help/AdvancedTutorial.aspx)
2. Use AJAX to poll for changes every `X` number of seconds. If changes are detected reload the page, otherwise do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look into the [SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx) object.  This object will notify you of changes to a specified database query in real time.  When your application receives a message from the database, you can simply refresh the page in your code-behind.

Comment: Any examples of this being used in an application?

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it doesn't communicate back to the client in real-time.

Comment: You're probably right James... once the page has loaded, it doesn't matter that the SqlDependency has been registered since the page is no longer actively executing.  I'm still thinking in WPF mode.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you could adapt SignalR to send a message to the client to prompt a refresh?

[This tutorial](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx) could get you started.